# How to synthesize tetrabutyl titanate from titanium dioxide powder?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, synthesis, reference-request, hydrolysis

How do you synthesize tetrabutyl titanate $(\ce{[CH3(CH2)3O]4Ti})$ from titanium dioxide ($\ce{TiO2}$) powder? As I know, we can get $\ce{TiO2}$ from tetrabutyl titanate, but how can we do the opposite?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE. We’d like you to take the [Tour](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiarized with the site. Meantime, let us know your thoughts about it as well. It’d help us to agree or disagree and give our feedback.

Comment: there is not practically viable way to do at at lab. It thousands time cheaper to go with titanium tetrachloride.

Answer (score 2):

Treat with a chlorination reagent the titania to form titanium tetrachloride. You could do this with coke and chlorine in an electric arc furnace. Then distill the titanium tetrachloride. Next react it with a mixture of sodium butoxide and butanol at a low temperture.

Next vacuum distill the product to obtain pure titanium butoxide